# RMI based cache channel messages in logs when using JMS

Tags: web8.5, cache

I'm installing SDL Web 8.5 in a distributed environment with separate servers for the deployer and delivery application. Due to the overly permissive firewall rules required by the RMI based cache channel service I have enabled JMS based cache invalidation using Apache ActiveMQ and it appears to be working properly. I am able to see expected invalidations and performance improvements. However I still see RMI related cache channel messages in the cd_core logs on the presentation server with the ip of my deployer:

```
RMICacheChannelConnector - Attempting to look up cache channel service on //10.1.1.10:1099/CacheChannelService
```

As you can see below I have no mention of the RMI in the delivery application's cd_storage_conf.xml:

```
    <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
        <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
            <Param Name="MemSize" Value="32mb"/>
        </Policy>
        <Features>
            <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
        </Features>
        <RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="60000" Queuesize="512">
            <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Strategy="AsyncJMS11" Topic="Tridion">
                <JndiContext>
                    <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                    <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="tcp://10.1.1.10:61616?soTimeout=5000"/>
                    <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="SDLWebCacheLive"/>
                </JndiContext>
            </Connector>
        </RemoteSynchronization>
    </ObjectCache>
```

Why do I still see the RMI Cache Channel messages? Is this expected? Is my cd_storage_conf.xml setup properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was just some old configuration that was stuck in my websphere instance. I rebuilt the application and redeployed the war and the messages went away.